# Can't programmatically fill address field on taxonomy term creation

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm creating some taxonomy terms inside of an update hook and they have a coordinates field and an address field containing only zipcode and locality.

The Vocabulary is called `cities`, the address field is called `field_cities_zip_city` and the coordinates are called `field_cities_coordinates`.

```
//the exact data that fails
$city = [
  'zip' => 1000,
  'name' => 'Lausanne',
  'lat' => '47.3879577',
  'lng' => '8.044136',
];


$term = Term::create([
  'name' => $city['zip'].' '.$city['name'],
  'vid' => 'cities',
  'field_cities_zip_city' => [
    'postal_code' => $city['zip'],
    'locality' => $city['name'],
  ],
  'field_cities_coordinates' => [
    'lat' => $city['lat'],
    'lng' => $city['lng'],
  ],
]);
$term->save();
```

What happens is, the term gets created, the coordinates get filled in properly, but the address remains empty despite even being required fields.

Trying like this did not change anything:

```
//the exact data that fails
$city = [
  'zip' => 1000,
  'name' => 'Lausanne',
  'lat' => '47.3879577',
  'lng' => '8.044136',
];


$term = Term::create([
  'name' => $city['zip'].' '.$city['name'],
  'vid' => 'cities',
  'field_cities_zip_city' => [
    'postal_code' => $city['zip'],
    'locality' => $city['name'],
  ],
  'field_cities_coordinates' => [
    'lat' => $city['lat'],
    'lng' => $city['lng'],
  ],
]);

//set the fields again manually, but this has no effect
$term->field_cities_zip_city->postal_code = $city['zip'];
$term->field_cities_zip_city->locality = $city['name'];

$term->save();
```

The address fields are still empty. What am I missing??
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could it be because you're not setting postal code properly? In your example above you are setting postal code to `$city['plz']` which doesn't appear to be defined.

Comment: Ah no that‘s a typo for the example :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the country_code to your address field.

like

```
$city = [
  'zip' => 1000,
  'name' => 'Lausanne',
  'lat' => '47.3879577',
  'lng' => '8.044136',
];


$term = Term::create([
  'name' => $city['zip'].' '.$city['name'],
  'vid' => 'cities',
  'field_cities_zip_city' => [
    'country_code' => 'CH',  // country code is required
    'postal_code' => $city['zip'],
    'locality' => $city['name'],
  ],
]);
$term->save();
```