# How to create an entity with a referenced entity

Tags: entities, commerce

I work with Drupal Commerce but my question is more related to a custom entity which refers to a custom entity.

Concretely, users have a profile. This profile contains fields including a field which refers to the address module.

I made a form with the form API to update the profile as well as the address fields. Everything works fine if the profile already exists.

If the user does not yet have a profile, I create the profile. The profile exists and I can update its fields except the address module fields. They are not present in the object. How to create them?

This is what doesn't work but what I had thought of among other things..

These are the fields of the address field which are not created when the profile object is created.

```
if (!($profile)) {
      // If no profile exists, create a new one.
      $profile = $profile_storage->create([
        'type' => $profile_type,
        'uid' => $user_id,
        'field_mobilephone' => '0000258',
        // fields are not crated
        'address' => [
          "langcode" => null,
          "country_code" => null,
          "administrative_area" => null,
          "locality" => "",
          "dependent_locality" => null,
          "postal_code" => '44400',
          "sorting_code" => null,
          "address_line1" => null,
          "address_line2" => null,
          "organization" => null,
          "given_name" => null,
          "additional_name" => null,
          "family_name" => null,
        ],
      ]);

      $profile->save();
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean an entity reference field type or a field type with address properties? In the second case you can specify field properties when creating entities like you did. But you can't tell from a debug output of private object properties if field values exist because they are lazy-loaded. As long as you don't use the public entity API to load the field values they are empty in the entity object.

Comment: Looking at the questions already asked for the address field, could it be, that you are simply missing the country code? See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/262035/47547